# Project web-site from published web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-deployment

I have published web-site.
Can I get Project web-site from published web-site (ASP.NET Web Forms)?

Comment: How do you want to get it? In code? In IIS? You need to provide much more detail before someone will be able to answer this.

Comment: i.e. you have a filesystem image of a published website? What does it look like - do you have .cs files, or is it all compiled into .dlls?

Comment: Are you saying you have a copy of a published website and need to open this in visual studio for editing?

Comment: Create a new project and add all files? Next time, use source control.

Comment: I haven't cs files only aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I get Project web-site from published web-site

Yes you can but **you shouldn't** unless you are the owner of the code.

But you will have to decompile each of the dll then create proper classes and a project and add them to your project.